# Printing objects in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Why do I get different results?

```perl6
class Car {
  has $.wheels;
}

my $my_car = Car.new( wheels => 4 );

say  $my_car ;  # Car.new(wheels => 4)
say "$my_car";  # Car<94582644384824>
put  $my_car ;  # Car<94582644384824>
```

I suppose that in the 2nd and 3rd cases `$my_car` is stringified, but what does the result mean?

Comment: At a guess, the "94582644384824" is a memory address and its part of the default non-human friendly stringification of a P6 object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `say` command calls `.gist` on its argument.  The `put` command calls `.Str` on its argument.  And this also happens when you interpolate your object.

The default `gist` method looks at the public attributes of an object, and creates a string from that.

You can control how your object gets stringified by supplying your own `Str` method.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. If an object is stringified with `.Str`, how can supplying my own `.gist` change how it gets stringified?

Comment: After some experimenting I think I understand what you meant with customizing `.gist`. What I still don't understand is why `.Str` doesn't give any (human-) useful info.

Comment: What useful info should (could?) it give? It is your class -- if you want some information, make a .Str() that gives it..  .gist() is for the human consumable stringification  .perl() is for computer consumption.  What are you planning to use .Str for with this class?

Comment: oops, I meant "your own `Str` method".  It was late.  Sorry.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Presumably Liz's typo was confusing. The English word "gist" means ["the most significant and essential part of something"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:gist). The `gist` in P6 aims at being a brief (truncating if necessary), friendly, useful summary for humans. `say` uses `gist`. In the meantime, the `Str` aims at being a quick, full, dumb stringification. `Str` is used by `put` and `print`. Finally `.perl` aims at providing a source code equivalent of its invocant. You're supposed to be able to feed its output back into the compiler and get the invocant back.

Comment: @raiph ElizabethMattijsen, CurtTilmes Thanks to everyone, now I understand it.